# Growth rate of Caucasian Shepherd Dogs

Tags: dogs, growing, age

Starting from [**this question**](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/37258/16373) I have another one: **what is the growth rate of Caucasian Shepherd Dogs?**

I think I am interested in the following details, as a minimum:

1. Size / weight at birth (mostly for curiosity reasons)
2. Size / weight at 3 months - the age at which the dog can be taken away from the mother.
3. At which age does the dog reach "adult size" (actual maturity might happen at a different age, I guess).

Note: Of course, the question is asked from a "statistical" / average POV. Each individual is unique, of course.

Comment: German wikipedia states, that adult boys are minimum heigth 68cm at shoulder...

Comment: Yes, i already have that info. Tnx anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Random search on the internet returned [this table](https://www.russiandog.net/what-is-caucasian-ovcharka-shepherd-growth-chart.html).

```
age/months   weight/kg
         1       4 - 7  
         2     13 - 19  
         3     18 - 32  
         4     25 - 60  
         5     35 - 64  
         6     40 - 94  
         7     42 - 99  
         8    44 - 104 
         9    45 - 110 
        10    46 - 115 
        11    48 - 120 
        12   Male: 50 - 125 (normally 50 – 70)
            Female: 40 - 100 (normally 40 – 60)
```

Beware: I don't think the upper limits are sensible (100 kg at 9 months age is not a healthy weight for any kind of dog, not even very big ones. The lower limits and the normal range given at 1 year seem plausible, though.).

[Wikipedia about Ovcharkas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caucasian_Shepherd_Dog) gives the usual weight range at 45 - 70 kg.

---

I have a [Greater Swiss Mountain Dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_Swiss_Mountain_Dog), they are slightly smaller. Other than that, I'd think their growth is quite similar.

Here's a table of the *recommended** weight range (by the [breeder's association](https://ssv-ev.de/)) during the first year:

```
age/months     weight/kg
         1    3.6 -  5.0
         2    8.5 - 11.4
         3   14.4 - 19.2  
         4   20.3 - 27.0
         5   23.4 - 31.2
         6   27.9 - 37.2
         7   30.6 - 40.8
         8   32.0 - 42.6
         9   33.0 - 43.8
        10   35.0 - 46.8
        11   37.0 - 49.2
        12   39.6 - 52.8
```

My male weighed

- 410 g at birth,
- about 11 kg when I took him at 11 weeks age,
- 40 kg at IIRC 9 months (when he reached about full height),
- and in the end levelled out somewhere around 52 kg.
  He grew noticeably wider and more muscular until about 3.

* recommended means that they'll feed like a vaccum cleaner in their first year if you let them, but it's better in particular for joint health if your restrict their growth rate (so I can well imagine how the huge upper limits in the other table come to happen). The breeder said it doesn't affect their final size, it's more about growing a bit more slowly.

Comment: Which height had your dog at 9 month? Or wich is given by your source? 70cm for the caucasian (female maximum, male minimum) seems for me a good reason for around 100kg ^^ And from the pictures this breed looks like a heavy one...

Comment: He's 72 cm at withers, breeder's association doesn't specify height. The Newfoundland was 84 cm / 75 kg - but also as fully grown adult (at 6). IIRC, a labrador retriever is considered obese (not just overweight) when 30 % above its ideal weight. 30 % above the 70 kg upper normal for fully grown males limit would be ≈90 kg, the upper limit of the growth chart crosses that at 6 months. I can easily see this happen (remembering the food craving my pup had), only I don't think it is healthy. 100 kg is above what is usual even for St Bernards, whose breed standard specifies 70 - 90+ cm (male).

Comment: I understand your reasons, but weight measurements without any number for height is simple "feeling" not "proove"